Multi Camera and Grease Pencil Line Art Modifier
Anyone know if there's a way to get the Grease Pencil Line Art modifier to work with Multi-View Stereoscopy? Trying to render out line art of a character from multiple angles at once. (Works with freestyle but you lose the intersecting lines.)
